# Windows: Which version of Unicode is supported?

Tags: windows, unicode, version, standards

I read that [`NormalizeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-normalizestring) normalizes strings "according to Unicode 4.0 TR#15". Moreover, I see that ["Using Unicode Normalization to Represent Strings"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-unicode-normalization-to-represent-strings) also mentions "Unicode 4.0".

Now, seeing that [Unicode 4.0 is from April 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Versions), I wonder if this information is still up-to-date. I strongly assume that newer Windows versions actually use a more recent Unicode version, but I can't seem to find any authoritative source for this assumption.

Is there any reference which Windows version supports which Unicode version?

Comment: I may be cynical, but I wouldn't trust any Win32 API to correctly handle recent Unicode versions. I'd go towards [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) for stuff like that: there you'll know exactly which version is supported and you can upgrade the library without depending on OS-upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know, and it could change between versions, but you can test it with these values (canonical normalization, if not explicit stated):

- Unicode 4.1: FA79 <-> 5555
- Unicode 5.0: 1B12 <-> 1B11 1B35
- Unicode 5.1: A770 -> A76F (compatibility)
- Unicode 5.2: FA6B <-> 6075
- Unicode 6.0: 2096 -> 006B (compatibility)
- Unicode 6.1: 1112E <-> 11131 11127
- Unicode 7.0: 1134B <-> 11347 1133E
- Unicode 8.0: no changes on decomposition
- Unicode 9.0: 1F23B -> 914D (compatibility)
- Unicode 10.0: no changes on decomposition
- Unicode 11.0: no changes on decomposition
- Unicode 12.0: 1F16C -> 004D 0052 (compatibility)
- Unicode 12.1: 32FF -> 4EE4 548C (compatibility)
- Unicode 13.0: 11935 <-> 11930

I've not yet updated my data to Unicode 14.

Comment: Unicode 15.0: ‍⬛ will turn into 1 emoji of a black bird.